# Raven matrix like puzzle

Tags: progressive-matrix

I found this puzzle on TONI test and it was hard for me. It is the last item on the test. Can someone help me to solve and explain the solution?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

My hunch is that the next item is...

> shape #3

...because...

> The number of subdivisions within each shape increases by one each time: a circle has one, a square split in half has two, etc. Shape #3, which would be the fifth shape in the sequence, is the only option with five subdivisions.

I'm unsure if this is the correct solution, since...

> it doesn't account for the smaller shapes within the larger shape. Perhaps these are just red herrings, which is why there are none in shape #3?